# How to subscribe to Single thing group things in a single subscribe topic in AWS IoT MQTT?

Tags: mqtt, aws-iot

How to subscribe to Single thing group things in a single subscribe topic in AWS IoT MQTT?

[image]

Usecase

Things List(ThingName)

1. xxxxx
2. xxxxx1
3. xxxx2
4. xxxxx3

....

55. xxxx55

I want to subscribe to all the things in a single subscription topic. because there is a limitation on AWS one connection has subscribed max of 50 subscription topics.

i want to subscribe : $aws/things/xxxxx???/shadow/update/accepted

Comment: Sorry, I mostly see a screenshot full of red squiggly lines and a single sentence, can you maybe elaborate on the problem?

Comment: @Maurice how to subscribe thing group on a single topic?

Comment: A have you tried using MQTT topic wildcards? e.g. `+`

Comment: $aws/things/xxxxx+/shadow/update/accepted it's not accepted topic

Comment: @hardillb An error occurred when subscribing to $aws/things/XXXXXXX+/shadow/update/accepted: Invalid topic $aws/things/XXXXXXX+/shadow/update/accepted

Comment: The `+` need to replace a whole topic level. e.g. `$aws/things/+/shadow/update/accepted`

Comment: @hardillb  topic subscribed but not received any message.

Comment: @hardillb
cloud watch log

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-05-18 10:48:25.811",
    "logLevel": "ERROR",
    "traceId": "ebd3be65-1f23-8f32-2e58-20136b9c0e7b",
    "accountId": "xxxxxxx",
    "status": "Failure",
    "eventType": "Subscribe",
    "protocol": "MQTT",
    "topicName": "$aws/things/+/shadow/update/accepted",
    "clientId": "xxxxxxx",
    "principalId": "AROAXKNP25MQMPBP5LL5R:CognitoIdentityCredentials",
    "sourceIp": "103.241.227.168",
    "sourcePort": 61822,
    "reason": "AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE",
    "details": "Authorization Failure"
}
```

Comment: I only asked if you'd tried it, it appears that AWS applies tighter rules than the basic MQTT specification. You will need somebody with AWS specific knowledge to help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244835/discussion-between-nalawala-murtuza-and-hardillb).